# C++ change sort method

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ struct sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698854/c-struct-sorting)

Is it possible to sort a vector in C++ according to a specified sorting method, like used in Java's Collections.sort that takes a Comparator?

Comment: Yes it is. Look for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698854/c-struct-sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  See the answers to this question from this morning: [C++ struct sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698854/c-struct-sorting)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) for an example.