# Creating a template predicate class requiring a pointer to method function, and ensuing compiler errors

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, predicate

I'm building a series of predicates that duplicate lots of code, and so are being changed into a single template function class based on the `std::unary_function`. The idea is that my class interface requires methods such as `Element_t Element()` and `std::string Name()` to be defined, so the predicate template arguments are the object type and a value type to which comparison will be made as follows:

```
// generic predicate for comparing an attribute of object pointers to a specified test value
template <class U, typename R>
class mem_fun_eq : public std::unary_function <U*, bool> {
  private:
    typedef R (U::*fn_t)();
    fn_t fn; 
    R val;
  public:
    explicit mem_fun_eq (fn_t f, R& r) : fn(f), val(r) { } 
    bool operator() (U * u) const {
      return (u->*fn)() == val;
    }   
};
```

Thus, if I have:

```
class Atom {
  public:
    const Element_t& Element() const { return _element; }
    const std::string& Name() const { return _name; }
};
```

I would like to perform a search on a container of `Atom`s and check for either the `Name` or `Element` equality using my template predicate like so:

```
typedef std::string (Atom::*fn)() const;

Atom_it it = std::find_if( _atoms.begin(), _atoms.end(), mem_fun_eq <Atom, std::string> ((fn)&Atom::Name, atomname));
```

but compiling this returns the following error on the `std::find_if` line:

```
error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
```

Also, trying to form the same predicate for a check of the `Element()` as such:

```
typedef Atom::Element_t& (Atom::*fn)() const;

Atom_it it = std::find_if(_atoms.begin(), _atoms.end(), mem_fun_eq <Atom, Atom::Element_t> ((fn)&Atom::Element, elmt);
```

creates a different error!

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘mem_fun_eq<Atom, Atom::Element_t>::mem_fun_eq(Atom::Element_t& (Atom::*)()const, const Atom::Element_t&)’
note: candidates are: mem_fun_eq<U, R>::mem_fun_eq(R (U::*)(), R&) [with U = Atom, R = Atom::Element_t]
note:                 mem_fun_eq<Atom, Atom::Element_t>::mem_fun_eq(const mem_fun_eq<Atom, Atom::Element_t>&)
```

Firstly, am I reinventing the wheel with this predicate? Is there something in the STL that I've missed that does the same job in a single class? I can always break the predicate down into several more specific ones, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Secondly, can you help me with the compiler errors?

Comment: I answered a similar question where the intent was comparing member attributes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202731/is-there-support-in-c-stl-for-sorting-objects-by-attribute/2202906#2202906)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any easy way to do this using the bits provided with the STL. There is probably some clever boost way, using iterator adapters, or boost::lambda, but personally I wouldn't go that way.

Obviously C++0x lambdas will make all this easy.

Your problem is attempting to cast a function like this:

```
const std::string&(Atom::*)()
```

into a function like this:

```
std::string (Atom::*)()
```

If you replace your `typedef R (U::*fn_t)();` with `typedef const R& (U::*fn_t)() const;` then it should work.

The following avoids this problem and also provides type inference so that you can just write `mem_fun_eq(&Atom::Name, atomname)`. It compiles for me, although I haven't tested it.

```
template<typename U, typename R, typename S>
class mem_fun_eq_t : public std::unary_function<U const*, bool>
{
private:
    R (U::*fn_)() const;
    S val_;
public:
    mem_fun_eq_t(R (U::*fn )() const, S val) : fn_(fn), val_(val){}
    bool operator()(U * u)
    {
        return (u->*fn_)() == val_;
    }
};

template<typename U, typename R, typename S>
mem_fun_eq_t<U, R, S> mem_fun_eq(R (U::*fn)() const, S val)
{
    return mem_fun_eq_t<U, R, S>(fn, val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of trying to mix in a `mem_fun_ref` or `mem_fun` object in place of the member function call?

Basically, you call on `mem_fun` to create an object that accepts two arguments `T*` and a template argument to the function `A` if it has one (or void if it doesn't).  Hence you combine it like so:

```
template<typename MemFunc, typename CompareType, typename T>
struct MyPredicate{
    MyPredicate(MemFunc _functionObj, CompareType _value) 
    : m_Value(_value),
    m_Function(_functionObj){}

    bool operator()(const T &_input){
         return m_Value == m_Function(_input);
    }

 private:
    MemFunc m_Function;
    CompareType m_Value;
 };
```

Edit:

Ok, that's not completely working so why not have:

```
struct NamePred: binary_function<Atom*,string,bool>{
    bool operator()(Atom *_obj, string _val){
        return _obj->Name() == _val;
    };
};
```

then use `bind2nd`

```
find_if( atoms.begin(), atoms.end(), bind2nd( NamePred, "yo" ) );
```

Comment: Yes, just having the type of the function be a template parameter makes most of the pain go away. You should do this.

Comment: Can the `MemFunc` type be deduced?

Comment: @Shamster: good point. A wrapper function would be required to achieve the required type deduction, similar to the mem_fun and mem_fun_ref wrapper functions.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get it to compile with VS2008 but that's exactly the problem I'm running into.  It's having issues with resolving the mem_fun return type.  Damn, thought this would help.  I'll keep working at it.