# STL sort issue with GCC

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I've been having issues with STL sort. I'm trying to sort a vector of objects by a data member in the object. I've looked up several examples, but once it falls into my configuration it somehow doesn't compile under GCC. I tested on Visual Studio and it works. I get this error on GCC:

`no match for call to '(test::by_sym) (const stock&, const stock&)`

What I don't understand is that the same code will compile on Visual Studio.

Here's my set up.

driver.cpp

```
DB t1;
t1.print();
cout << "---sorting---" << endl;
t1.sSort();
t1.print();
```

class DB

```
vector<stock> list;

struct by_sym {
bool operator()(stock &a, stock &b)  {
return a.getSymbol() < b.getSymbol();
}
};

void DB::sSort(){
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), by_sym());
}
```

and my stock class just has the data members.

Is there a workaround on GCC?

I believe my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202731/is-there-support-in-c-stl-for-sorting-objects-by-attribute), but the solutions on there are not working for me.

Answer (score 6):

Your `operator()()` is const-incorrect. Change it to

```
bool operator()(const stock& a, const stock& b) const
```

Make sure `stock::getSymbol()` is also a `const` function. If it isn't and you can't change it then take the parameters of `operator()()` by value, not by (const) reference.

Comment: GCC really enforces const doesn't it...whereas the MSVC implementation doesn't? and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all - apparently the G++ STL implementation expects a comparison predicate to take const arguments. Try changing the declaration of operator() to

```
bool operator()(const stock &a, const stock &b)
```

and check if it helps.

Comment: 25.3/2: "It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator". GCC is assuming it pretty actively ;-)