# How to use the priority queue STL for objects?

Tags: c++, stl

```
class Person
{
public:
    int age;
};
```

I want to store objects of the class Person in a priority queue.

```
priority_queue< Person, vector<Person>, ??? >
```

I think I need to define a class for the comparison thing, but I am not sure about it.

Also, when we write,

```
priority_queue< int, vector<int>, greater<int> >
```

How does the greater work?

Comment: Similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912595/initialization-for-stl-priority-queue)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to provide a valid strict weak ordering comparison for the type stored in the queue, `Person` in this case. The default is to use `std::less<T>`, which resolves to something equivalent to `operator<`. This relies on it's own stored type having one. So if you were to implement

```
bool operator<(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs);
```

it should work without any further changes. The implementation could be

```
bool operator<(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs)
{
  return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}
```

If the the type does not have a natural "less than" comparison, it would make more sense to provide your own predicate, instead of the default `std::less<Person>`. For example,

```
struct LessThanByAge
{
  bool operator()(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
  }
};
```

then instantiate the queue like this:

```
std::priority_queue<Person, std::vector<Person>, LessThanByAge> pq;
```

Concerning the use of `std::greater<Person>` as comparator, this would use the equivalent of `operator>` and have the effect of creating a queue with the priority inverted WRT the default case. It would require the presence of an `operator>` that can operate on two `Person` instances.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I dislike the use of `operator<` here. `operator<` implements the default comparison for a type, which, in my experience, is rarely what you want. I think the approach Mike describes in his answer is almost always preferable.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Agreed. I was adding something about that. In a class with only one data member, the operator *might* have made sense.

Comment: Worthy to note: implementing `bool YourClass::operator <(const YourClass&) const` will also allow transparent use of the default comparator, `std::less<T>`. Not as flexible, but functional when that is all you need. (and +1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can overload '<' operator even if the class has multiple members, right?

Comment: @user2441151 Yes, you can, but you have to be careful with the logic. It must implement a strict weak ordering. The more data members, the easier it is to get it wrong. That's unless you use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), in which case it is quite trivial.

Answer (score 53):

You would write a comparator class, for example:

```
struct CompareAge {
    bool operator()(Person const & p1, Person const & p2) {
        // return "true" if "p1" is ordered before "p2", for example:
        return p1.age < p2.age;
    }
};
```

and use that as the comparator argument:

```
priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, CompareAge>
```

Using `greater` gives the opposite ordering to the default `less`, meaning that the queue will give you the lowest value rather than the highest.

Comment: It's possible to pass "comparator objects" instead of comparator classes? (in order to parametrize it and obtain more flexibility)

Comment: @castarco yes, you can pass a specific comparator object as a constructor argument.

Comment: This is a more preferable method to the top answer. Not only because it achieves a higher level comparison (that can easily be transferred in other languages, lower and higher level), but also because it results in more reusable code.

Answer (score 20):

A priority queue is an abstract data type that captures the idea of a container whose elements have "priorities" attached to them.  An element of highest priority always appears at the front of the queue.   If that element  is removed, the next  highest priority  element  advances to the front.

The C++ standard library defines a class template priority_queue, with the following operations:

**push**:  Insert an element into the prioity queue.

**top**: Return (without removing it) a highest priority element from the priority queue.

**pop**: Remove a highest priority element from the priority queue.

**size**: Return the number of elements in the priority queue.

**empty**: Return true or false according to whether the priority queue is empty or not.

The following code snippet shows how to construct two priority queues, one that can contain integers and another one that can contain character strings:

```
#include <queue>

priority_queue<int> q1;
priority_queue<string> q2;
```

The following is an example of priority queue usage:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  // This is to make available the names of things defined in the standard library.

int main()
{
    piority_queue<string> pq; // Creates a priority queue pq to store strings, and initializes the queue to be empty.

    pq.push("the quick");
    pq.push("fox");
    pq.push("jumped over");
    pq.push("the lazy dog");

    // The strings are ordered inside the priority queue in lexicographic (dictionary) order:
    // "fox", "jumped over", "the lazy dog", "the quick"
    //  The lowest priority string is "fox", and the highest priority string is "the quick"

    while (!pq.empty()) {
       cout << pq.top() << endl;  // Print highest priority string
       pq.pop();                    // Remmove highest priority string
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
the quick
the lazy dog
jumped over
fox
```

Since a queue follows a priority discipline, the strings are printed from highest to lowest priority.

Sometimes one needs to create a priority queue to contain user defined objects.  In this case, the priority queue needs to know the comparison criterion used to determine which objects have the highest priority.  This is done by means of a function object belonging to a class that overloads the operator ().  The overloaded () acts as < for the purpose of determining priorities.  For example, suppose we want to create a priority queue to store Time objects.  A Time object has three fields: hours, minutes, seconds:

```
struct Time {
    int h; 
    int m; 
    int s;
};

class CompareTime {
    public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2) // Returns true if t1 is earlier than t2
    {
       if (t1.h < t2.h) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m < t2.m) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m == t2.m && t1.s < t2.s) return true;
       return false;
    }
}
```

A priority queue to store times according the the above comparison criterion would be defined as follows:

```
priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;

Here is a complete program:

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Time {
    int h; // >= 0
    int m; // 0-59
    int s; // 0-59
};

class CompareTime {
public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2)
    {
       if (t1.h < t2.h) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m < t2.m) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m == t2.m && t1.s < t2.s) return true;
       return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;

    // Array of 4 time objects:

    Time t[4] = { {3, 2, 40}, {3, 2, 26}, {5, 16, 13}, {5, 14, 20}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       pq.push(t[i]);

    while (! pq.empty()) {
       Time t2 = pq.top();
       cout << setw(3) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " <<
       setw(3) << t2.s << endl;
       pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints the times from latest to earliest:

```
5  16  13
5  14  20
3   2  40
3   2  26
```

If we wanted earliest times to have the highest priority, we would redefine CompareTime like this:

```
class CompareTime {
public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2) // t2 has highest prio than t1 if t2 is earlier than t1
    {
       if (t2.h < t1.h) return true;
       if (t2.h == t1.h && t2.m < t1.m) return true;
       if (t2.h == t1.h && t2.m == t1.m && t2.s < t1.s) return true;
       return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have a question, if I may. priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq; . Why is the second parameter, vector<Time> necessary? I have seen it in numerous snippets of code but I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Oh noo...the fox is not brown and non-brown fox jumped (jumpes) over the lazy dog. :-(

Comment: Shouldn't pq.front() be pq.top() in the first snippet?

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code may help..

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;    

class node{
public:
    int age;
    string name;
    node(int a, string b){
        age = a;
        name = b;
    }
};

bool operator<(const node& a, const node& b) {

    node temp1=a,temp2=b;
    if(a.age != b.age)
        return a.age > b.age;
    else{
        return temp1.name.append(temp2.name) > temp2.name.append(temp1.name);
    }
}

int main(){
    priority_queue<node> pq;
    node b(23,"prashantandsoon..");
    node a(22,"prashant");
    node c(22,"prashantonly");
    pq.push(b);
    pq.push(a);
    pq.push(c);

    int size = pq.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout<<pq.top().age<<" "<<pq.top().name<<"\n";
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
22 prashantonly
22 prashant
23 prashantandsoon..
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define user defined comparator: .The code below can be helpful for you.

### Code Snippet :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct man
{
  string name;
  int priority; 
};

class comparator
{
 public:
   bool operator()(const man& a, const man& b)
   {
        return a.priority<b.priority;
   }
};

int main()
{
   man arr[5];
   priority_queue<man, vector<man>, comparator> pq;

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
     cin>>arr[i].name>>arr[i].priority;
     pq.push(arr[i]);
   }

   while (!pq.empty())
   {
     cout<<pq.top().name<<" "<<pq.top().priority;
     pq.pop();
     cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**input :**

> batman 2
>   goku  9
>   mario 4

**Output**

> goku  9
>   mario 4
>   batman 2