# Time complexity of a Priority Queue in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, priority-queue

Creating a heap takes `O(n)` time while inserting into a heap (or priority queue) takes `O(log(n))` time.

**Taking n inputs and inserting them into the priority queue, what would be the time complexity of the operation?**  O(n) or O(n*log(n)).

Also, the same result would hold in case of emptying the entire heap too (i.e. n deletions), right?

Comment: Let me direct you to the documentation: [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Comment: @Rakete1111 this is a Q/A site in case you've forgotten

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you have an array of size `n` and you want to build a heap from all items at once, Floyd's algorithm can do it with O(n) complexity. See [Building a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap). This corresponds to the [std::priority_queue constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) that accept a container parameter.

If you have an empty priority queue to which you want to add `n` items, one at a time, then the complexity is O(n * log(n)).

So if you have all of the items that will go into your queue before you build it, then the first method will be more efficient. You use the second method--adding items individually--when you need to maintain a queue: adding and removing elements over some time period.

Removing `n` items from the priority queue also is O(n * log(n)).

Documentation for [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) includes runtime complexity of all operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974470/efficiency-of-the-stl-priority-queue has more explanation on this.  The first answer in there says pop/remove is O(2*log(N)).  Does it mean in your case, "Removing n items from the priority queue also is O(n * log(n))." should be modified to "Removing n items from the priority queue also is O(n * 2* log(n))."? or it does not matter?

Comment: @RaghavNavada In asymptotic analysis, we typically ignore constant factors. So O(n*log(n)) is considered the same as O(n*2*log(n)).

Comment: what will be time complexity if we build stl priority queue from vector?Will it call insert method again and again and takes nlogn or will it be like normal build heap in 0(n).

Comment: @rahulsharma It takes O(n)